# Overlay label, list and a button on top of an image on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make a page where there is a picture and basically the everything else on the page on top of the image.

Something similar to this

[image]

XAML Code like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Project.Page">
<ScrollView>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="{Binding ContentImage}}"  Aspect="AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding label}" FontSize="15" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,-1,-1" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I have this so far. But this only has the label way at the bottom right, and I can't seem to get the list or buttons to work properly. I was thinking maybe just have the image be the background, but the image is supposed to change by the push of a button or something and I am not entirely sure if you can do that with a background image.

Is something like this possible with Xamarin.Forms?

Sorry if my English is poor! It's my second language!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I was able to use the image as background and change by a button click. Now I just need to find out how to actually position a ListView.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I moved some items around from a demo, this is *just* one way to handle it using an AbsoluteLayout and Grid

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewLayout">
    <Image Source="coffee.png" Aspect="AspectFill" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,.50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="#66000000" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,20,20,20" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1">
            <Grid Margin="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Salted Caramel Mocha Frappuccino" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                <Button Text="Extra Shot" BackgroundColor="#77000000" BorderRadius="4" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
                <Button Text="Whipped Cream" BackgroundColor="#77000000" BorderRadius="4" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Text="Tall (12oz)" BackgroundColor="#77000000" BorderRadius="4" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Button Text="Grande (16oz)" BackgroundColor="#77000000" BorderRadius="4" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Button Text="Venti (20oz)" BackgroundColor="#77000000" BorderRadius="4" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it will work like a charm. Now I'm just wondering if adding a listview to this layout would work similarly?

Comment: Also is there a way for list items to show up horizontally like in the image?

Comment: @FrostZone `ListView` is strictly vertical, you should look at `CarouselView` in order to do left-right paging of controls and views