# xamarin forms absolute layout draw shape based on coordinate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using coordinates on absolute layout to mark some points i.e.:

```
new Point() { X = 0, Y = 0 };
new Point() { X = 0, Y = 300 };
new Point() { X = 200, Y = 0 };
```

How to draw a lines from point to point, connect them, in this case triangle shape?

Comment: use SkiaSharp - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/

Comment: use NGraphics ;-) - https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics

Comment: Thanks guys I totally forgot about SkiaSharp, don't know what I was thinking, in fact they have a full example how to make what I want: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/paths/lines/

Answer (score 0):

`SkiaSharp` is great, but if you do not need  all of Skia's features, the overhead of native libraries, increased app size, init times, and memory consumption can be avoided with NControl/NGraphics.

In terms of drawing a path of points, here is a really quick example:

#### NControlView Subclass that draws a list of NGraphics' `PathOp`:

```
public class PathControl : NControlView
{
    public IEnumerable<PathOp> Path { get; set; }

    public override void Draw(ICanvas canvas, Rect rect)
    {
        if (Path != null)
            canvas.DrawPath(Path, new Pen(Colors.Red, 5));
    }
}
```

#### Runtime assignment:

You can then assign the `IEnumerable<PathOp>` at runtime:

```
pathControl.Path = new PathOp[] {
    new MoveTo (40, 60),
    new LineTo (120, 60),
    new LineTo (80, 30),
    new ClosePath ()
};
pathControl.Invalidate();
```

#### Xaml:

Taking the XAML from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921938/overlay-label-list-and-a-button-on-top-of-an-image-on-xamarin-forms/46923658#46923658) and adding:

```
<nc:PathControl x:Name="pathControl" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
```

You can produce this:

[image]

With more vector work, something like this:

[image]

#### Other NControl/NGraphics answers/examples:

[image]

re: [Xamarin.Forms - How To Achieve 45 deg. Angled Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949635/xamarin-forms-how-to-achieve-45-deg-angled-background-color/36951593#36951593)

[image]

re: [Creating completeness meter (Status display) in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302315/creating-completeness-meter-status-display-in-xamarin/47465981#47465981)

[image]

re: [Pop Up in xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912031/pop-up-in-xamarin-forms/45916581#45916581)